# Linux weird Folder Permission needed (CentOs)

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, centos, directory

I don't know if what  I am asking now is possible, but if it is, that would be great.

I have a public folder where some users have access. I want to prevent all these users from creating subfolders into it. They should be able to create files like `touch note.txt` but not being able to create other folders.

I was thinking if I could disable `mkdir` command locally for the folder would do, but I don't know even if its possible.

Comment: That's impossible because directories and files are almost the same things. But if you want, you can monitor that directory by `inotify` and delete all directories when they will be created.

Comment: Well ok I see, but in windows it is possible, huh ...

Comment: how did you do it in win?

Comment: you have to play with advanced ACLs

Comment: I think, it was so simple in windows because of its holey architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not an programming question - so http://superuser.com is the better place to ask.

AFAIK (i'm not an Centos guru) - it is not possible to do with CentOS. For this type of permissions you need OS what supporting extended ACL. For example: Solaris ZFS, or Mac OS X and so on. Changing the underlaying OS is probably not a solution for you, so here is one another possibility - but not easy.

You can use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net) and make a program what will act as filesystem bridge and simple would not allow creating directories. As I told - not a trivial solution, but possible. For the low volume usage you can use perl for implementing filesystems in perl, through the FUSE kernel/lib interface. See [Fuse](http://search.cpan.org/~dpavlin/Fuse-0.14/Fuse.pm). For some basic tutorial you can check [this site](http://blogs.perl.org/users/fuzzix/2012/08/fun-with-fuse.html).

Sounds silly? Yes, it is. Maybe someone know an easy way setting up ACL on Centos. At least it is an "programmming solution". :).

Answer (score 0):

In principle, [SELinux](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) should allow that level of control, but don't ask me how to configure it.